# Macbook Pro 8,1 - wireless interface not showing up

Tags: 11.10, wireless, mac

I've installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my Macbook Pro 8,1. Everything went fine and everything installs fine except for the wireless interface.

I've installed the b43 module according to these instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro8-1/Natty#Wireless

I've tried compiling the module, `ndiswrapper` and also the last solution mentioned using this PPA: `ppa:zwaldowski/ppa`.

With the three solutions, the module loads finely. It works smoothly. `lspci` shows the wireless card without problem.

But there is no wireless interface. `iwconfig` or `ifconfig` both show `eth0` and `lo` as interfaces, but no `eth1` or `wlan0` interface is showing up.

I have no idea why, and I'm completely stuck there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I first got it to work by doing the decently complex b43 firmware extraction then using a backported 3.2 kernel. Anyhow, the method in the Oneiric MBP 8,2 page works much more easily, and functions just fine on my Macbook Pro 8,1 (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro8-2/Oneiric)

Add the mactel repository and install relevant packages:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mpodroid/mactel
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.2-oneiric-generic
```

Now edit the file '/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf'

```
gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

and add the line `blacklist ndiswrapper`

Now edit (Create if it doesn't exist) the file '/etc/pm/config.d/modules',

```
gksu gedit /etc/pm/config.d/modules
```

and add the line `SUSPEND_MODULES="b43 bcma"`

Reboot the computer, and you should be good to go. Much easier than doing the b43 firmware and compat-wireless stuff manually, and much more stable than ndiswrapper!

Comment: Thanks! I'll do this this weekend and keep you informed :)

Comment: Ok, it's working right out of the box! Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: how do you edit those files? Do I have to do it in the terminal?

Comment: anyone got this working in quantal?